# How to Auto Copy text file from one folder to another folder in vb 2010 console or windows application

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a program that auto copy text file from one folder to another folder . is it possible to make in windows form in vb.net ? if not what about in console apps ? i tried to search but i didn't find an answer for both. please help me i'm new to to this. I want to copy all the text file that is being save to c:folder1\test1.text copy to c:folder2\test1.text then test2.text,test3.text all the text file that are being put in folder1. i want to copy in folder2.
now i only have this code: 
it will only copy 1 specific textfile with file name test.txt.

`enter code here`

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\CopyTo\test.txt", 
"C:\CopyHere\test.txt")
```

Comment: Unfortunately we won't code your homework for you. Show us, what you've tried so far and tell us, where your code don't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: You should probably look at timers and/or filesystem watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! First of all we need a function that search for files.

```
Public Sub SearchFiles(ByVal Pattern As String, ByVal Path As String, ByVal FilesFound As ArrayList)
    FilesFound.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern))
End Sub
```

But where we should save the list of files? We can use a Array for it. Also we should define our output and input folder

```
Dim files As New ArrayList
Dim inDir As String = "input path"
Dim outDir As String = "output path"
```

We can now call this function like this:

```
SearchFiles("*.txt", inDir, files)
```

All .txt files in the folder are now saved in our Array List. But how we can work with it? We can now work with it like this:

```
Try
  For Each file As String In files
    Dim fName As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(file , outDir & "\" & fName, overwrite:=False)
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
  Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

This will copy every .txt file that where found in our inDir to our outDir. If something goes wrong then you will see this in the console. Try it out and understand how it works :)

Comment: thank you very much for spending time , i will try your code, will it work also in windows form ?

Comment: @Bonito why it should not work with windows forms? it is vb.net! it works the same in a form, in a console or in a service.

Comment: what would i put in SearchFiles() parameters ?? sorry i'm really new to vb.net . `SearchFiles(Pattern:=".txt", Path:="C:\CopyTo\test.txt", FilesFound:=".file")`  i try that code but the filefound has error.

Comment: @Bonito why did you edited the code like this? so basically you just need to call it like above: `SearchFiles("*.txt", inDir, files)` - just don't forget to add the definition of the ArrayList (in my example I called it files) and the Input Folder (in my example the inDir String) and of course you need to add the SearchFiles Function to your code.

Comment: I add the code in a button, so when i click it , i expected it will auto copy already all the files in inDir  to outDir but nothing happens. where i am wrong ?

Comment: @Bonito check the console. if anything is wrong it should be noted there.

Comment: `Dim files As New ArrayList
    Dim inDir As String = "C:\CopyTo"
    Dim outDir As String = "C:\CopyHere`

Comment: I write it in windows form like this. `  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

` no error shows..

Comment: ok now i try console and show error like this `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: I don't know what you done but [here is the code](https://gist.github.com/MarcoPNS/17e417e04539c3e78fb1db9814c7cc28)

Comment: i copy and do exactly what you said but now when i click the button still not copying the file in outDir, not show any message also in console. btw i am using vb.2010 window7. i run it in windows form apps. not in console.

Comment: @Bonito this is not possible. The code works perfectly. There need to be something. could you show me your complete code.

Comment: here is my code :
 [link]https://gist.github.com/emilladia/4d6aa81a9bacd2df97e28cbc1522e587

Comment: @Bonito Just edited your [code here](https://gist.github.com/MarcoPNS/c4f33851c882fa45eef2bc3afed84a0b)

Comment: thank you very much for your help i really appreciate it . your the man!!!!the problem is with me.i was confuse in indir and outdir. now its ok...

Comment: one more thing how can i auto copy it to other folder ? as soon as i put file in folder1 it should be copy automatic ? is that possible?

Comment: @Bonito You can put the code in a timer. set the interval to 10000 (which is 10 seconds) and try it out.

Comment: yes i got it. but what if i want to copy all files stored in folder1 to folder2 ? not only .txt ? is that possible?

Comment: @Bonito just change the call of the SearchFiles function. Instead of *.txt you just search for *

Comment: I tried what you said. 
       ` SearchFiles("* –", txtPathCF.Text, files)` but nothing happens